# Is it possible to export iTerm2 window arrangement?

Tags: iterm2

Is there any possible way to export iTerm2 window arrangement? I notice that it is not part of the profile(Json file you can export)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, all you have to do is:

```
iTerm -> Preferences -> General -> Preferences
```

Then, you will notice at the bottom of the panel, there is a setting called *Load preferences from a custom folder or URL*. Activate it and browse where you want to export the settings. Finally, there is a button next to it *Save settings to Folder*. Click it and it will save your settings.

Save this file for example in Dropbox and then import doing the same you did before.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using tabs instead of windows but I appreciate your help!

Comment: Albert, I'm not seeing this actually re-instate Arrangements..?

Comment: Which version do you have? It hasn't changed in my version: iTerm2 v3.1.7